# Enable CORS on server generated by Swagger-Editor

Tags: cors, swagger-editor

I am experimenting with Swagger and receive CORS errors when trying to browse the server with Swagger-UI.

I have only just discovered Swagger, and have been using the "Generate Node.js Server" feature from Swagger-Editor to get the server built and running locally.

**Is there a way to generate the server with CORS enabled?**